# Sharing Spacy model between processes

Tags: python-multiprocessing, spacy

My code is using Python's multiprocessing for parallel computation. As part of the computation Spacy is used. Is it safe to create a single spacy object with `nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_lg")` and access it by multiple processes for named entity recognition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantange of multiprocessing with spaCy by passing the `n_process` argument to `nlp.pipe`. For example:

```py
docs = ["This is the first doc", "this is the second doc"]

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")  # use your model here

docs_tokens = []
for doc in nlp.pipe(docs, n_process=2):
    tokens = [t.text for t in doc]
    docs_tokens.append(tokens)
```

There's more about this in the [spaCy documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#multiprocessing), as well as this [Speed FAQ](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8402#multiprocessing).